# How to limit number of buttons dispaly in cakephp pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I'm using cakephp 2.x and i'm trying to customize cakephp default pagination. I want to reduce number of buttons in pagination (cakephp default give 8 buttons) without changing number of result per page. Is it there any method to do that ?? Any help gratefully received :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. As many other things as well you can figure this out by simply checking and [reading the documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-PaginatorHelper.html#_numbers) for PaginatorHelper::numbers():

> Options:
>
> - `modulus` how many numbers to include on either side of the current page, defaults to 8.